# Only first RewriteRile working in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 rewrite rules in my htacces file, but only the first one is working

To remove .php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

To edit my url blog-detailed.php?id=1 to blog/1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ blog-detailed.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have rules in this order:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ blog-detailed.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```